# ExpandableList of Navigation Drawer populates only last item of the array

Tags: android, expandablelistadapter

When I try to populate navigation drawer item(childItem) under one single header, I get only last item of the array and get amount same as array size for the item(last item of the array)

also if I have 2 headers and try to populate their childItems each header only gets 2 items from its own arraylist.

this is my adapter class it looks like.

public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

```
private Context context;
private List<String> listDataHeader; // header titles
private  HashMap<String, List<NavigationViewHolder>> listDataChild;

public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,  HashMap<String, List<NavigationViewHolder>> listChildData) {
    this.context = context;
    this.listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
    this.listDataChild = listChildData;
}


@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
    return listDataChild.get(this.listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosititon);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final NavigationViewHolder childObj = (NavigationViewHolder) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_navigation_section, null);
    }

    TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.navig_body_section_item_title);
    ImageView imgChildView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.navig_body_section_item_icon);
  //  imgChildView.setImageResource(childObj.getImageId());
    txtListChild.setText(childObj.getTitleId());



    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return listDataChild.size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return this.listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return this.listDataHeader.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_navigation_section_header, null);
    }

    TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.navi_body_section_header_title);
    lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: In getChildrenCount() you should be returning listDataChild.get(this.listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).size().

Comment: but I dont work with the size anyway. why should I care about it for now?

Comment: its not working. it still is populating the last item of the array as amount of the array size